# How do I iterate through data in my class using ecmascript2015 in a javascript array like way?

Tags: meteor, ecmascript-6

I was hoping to iterate through my custom class data in a way similar to an array in javascript.  I would like to create a class that appears to be just a simple array but has much more complex data that can be manipulated with various member functions but iterated by various 3rd party functions that expect an array.

```
fruits=new Fruits('apple','orange','pear');

for(let fruit of fruits) {
    console.log(fruit);
}
```

or

```
for(var i=0;i<fruits.length;i++) {
    console.log("fruit["+i+"]: "+fruits[i]);
}
console.log("# of fruits: "+fruit.length);
```

using a class definition of:

```
Fruits = class Fruits {
    constructor(fruitArray) {
        this.fruitArray=fruitArray;
    }
    * [Symbol.iterator]() {
        for (let fruit of this.fruitArray) {
            yield fruit;
        }
    }
}
```

but I keep getting the following error: (I'm using Meteor 1.2 and the ecmascript package)

Fruit.prototype[Symbol.iterator] = function* () {
SyntaxError: Unexpected token *

Update * - ecmascript package.js is used by Meteor 1.2, so I assume support should exist for the babel subset with the default options.  http://babeljs.io/docs/learn-es2015/#classes

```
const babelOptions = Babel.getDefaultOptions();
return Babel.compile(command, babelOptions).code;
```

I did notice in babel docs it says...

> In order to use Iterators you must include the Babel polyfill.

So I included meteor add ecmascript-collections which includes polyfill subset, but that didn't make a difference.

Comment: At the moment, I don't think Meteor 1.2 ecmascript includes these ES2015 functionalities, see for yourself : https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/ecmascript

Comment: I looked at that. Github seems to show that the meteor ecmascript is the babel subset of functionality and the corresponding link suggests that iterators are supported in classes. babeljs.io/docs/learn-es2015/#classes, but without the asterik character which also doesn't compile? So I'm not sure it isn't supported.

Comment: For that array indexing behaviour, you'll likely need proxies, which afaik hardly can be polyfilled at all. So if you are not executing this code in an actual ES6 environment, you are out of luck.